# Android Studio: can't add class to <receiver> in AndroidManifest

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, receiver

I have done everything exactly as tutorial shows but I still get one error...I have created new activity SmsReceiver.java and there is everything OK but in the manifest when I try to add this

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">  // <-- this is problem
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

It doesn't want to accept that class .SmsReceiver....

I have tried everything please help. When i hover mouse over  it says " 'class' or 'interface' expected ".

[Here is package view and manifest full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzQuy.png)

This is SmsReceiver.java code

```
package com.dreamdev.matko.smsarduino;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdu");

        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
            SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

            String from = sms.getOriginatingAddress();

            String msg = sms.getDisplayMessageBody();

            Toast.makeText(context, "Prišla správa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Provide the full manifest.

Comment: try to remove the dot

Comment: Add fully-qualified name. Make sure the class SmsReceiver is in the same package as the declared at the top of the manifest file.

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your Android package view and the full Manifest.xml

Comment: I added package view and manifest.xml....Removing the dot doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> I have created new activity SmsReceiver.java

If you have created an `Activity`, then you cannot declare it in the manifest as a `BroadcastReceiver`. If you want to have a `BroadcastReceiver` then your class needs to `extend BroadcastReceiver` and then you add it to the manifest like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
```

Comment: I know, and it extends. I also tried to do this <receiver android:name=".MainActiviry"> and it didnt work but I'm new in android apps so..

Comment: Post your code and your complete manifest. You are confusing `Activity` and `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Ok now it is both posted.

Comment: Sorry, no ideas. It all looks just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please extend the class as a BroadcastReceiver in your .java file. Like below

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    ......
}
```